# How to get the href content from the html element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/nicolas_federman-det-2658430.aspx" title="Apartamento en Venta - Bogotá Nicolás de Federmán">
   <div>
      <h2 class="h2-grid">
         Apartamento en Bogotá - Nicolás De Federmán
      </h2>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div>
      Cundinamarca
   </div>
</a>
, 
<a href="/apartamento-en-venta/ibague/multicentro-det-2952281.aspx" title="Apartamento en Venta - Ibagué Multicentro">
   <div>
      <h2 class="h2-grid">
         Apartamento en Ibagué - Multicentro
      </h2>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div>
      Tolima
   </div>
</a>
, 
<a href="/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/bella_suiza-det-2865659.aspx" title="Apartamento en Venta - Bogotá Bella Suiza">
   <div>
      <h2 class="h2-grid">
         Apartamento en Bogotá - Bella Suiza
      </h2>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div>
      Cundinamarca
   </div>
</a>
, 
<a href="/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/cedritos-det-2844663.aspx" title="Apartamento en Venta - Bogotá Cedritos">
   <div>
      <h2 class="h2-grid">
         Apartamento en Bogotá - Cedritos
      </h2>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div>
      Cundinamarca
   </div>
</a>
, 
<a href="/oficina-en-venta/bogota/usaquen-det-3036032.aspx" title="Oficina en Venta - Bogotá Usaquén">
   <div>
      <h2 class="h2-grid">
         Oficina en Bogotá - Usaquén
      </h2>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div>
      Cundinamarca
   </div>
</a>
```

How can I get the 'aspx' link from the above html element. From the above html content I need to fetch the following value

```
/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/nicolas_federman-det-2658430.aspx
/apartamento-en-venta/ibague/multicentro-det-2952281.aspx
/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/bella_suiza-det-2865659.aspx
/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/cedritos-det-2844663.aspx
```

I've used the following python code to fetch the html element, need to know how to get the aspx value
url = 'https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/?ad=30|2||||1||||||||||||||||||||||1|||1||||||'

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'lxml')
index = soup.findAll('div' , 'span-title')
x = []
for i in index:
    x.append(i.find('a'))
print (x)
```

I've posted the url above the code to input it to the python code

Comment: You'll have to use regular expressions for that, goes something like
`soup.find(href=re.compile('''someregex''))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get('href')` after you find the `<a>` tags.

```
for i in index:
    x.append(i.find('a').get('href'))
```

Comment: it works like charm, solved my issue, thank you once again

Comment: unfortunately the page was loading slow here and unable to accept.so only commented immediatley